# Limit with l'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $x_1\geq ... \geq x_n = 0$ with $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$, $X =\left\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in [0,1]^n: x_1 \geq ... \geq x_n\right\},$ and $F$ be a twice continuously differentiable function with $F'(0)>0$. Evaluate the following limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0, \ x\in X} \frac{F\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x_1)(1-2z)}{1-x_1 + \sum_{m=2}^n m (x_{m-1}-x_m)z^{m-1}}dz\right)}{F\left(1-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x_1)}{1-x_1 + \sum_{m=2}^n m (x_{m-1}-x_m)z^{m-1}}dz\right)}.
\end{equation}

> Attempt: both the numerator and the denominator converge to zero.  Therefore, I apply l'Hopital's rule.  However, I still get zero divided by zero. I guess that I should apply l'Hopital's rule again, but that does not seem like a good approach.

Comment: Wow, the first post since a long time allowing l' Hopital! You don't believe me? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123413/finding-a-limit-without-lhopitals-rule-or-any-series) for example and the related posts.

Comment: I have two ideas for this kind of limit. 1: this is not a single variable limit, hence L'Hopital can't be used. 2: if the limit exists, then we can simplify a lot by considering vectors $x$ satisfying $x_1=x_2= \dots = x_n$. Under this assumption you get $$\lim_{x} \frac{F(0)}{F(0)}$$ and in the case that $F(0)=0$ I think that the limit simply does not exist.